# How to loop through Hash with multiple values and use destroy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code:

```
a = {"type1"=>[11], "type2"=>[12], "type3"=>[13, 14]}

a.each do |i, k|
  record = Model.where(type: i, id: k)
  record.destroy if record
end
```

In the 1st iteration, destroy action works fine with:

`Model.where(type: type1, id: 11)`

In the 2nd iteration, destroy action works fine with:

`Model.where(type: type2, id: 12)`

In the 3rd iteration, destroy action FAILS with:

`Model.where(type: type3, id: [13,14])`

In the 3rd iteration, `destroy` will fail because the query returns two records, and the destroy action will fail because it sends wrong number of arguments (1 instead of 2).

If I use `destroy_all`, it will work for the 3rd iteration, but will fail for the first two.

How can I fix the solution above?

Comment: Have you actually tried running this code? The `destroy` action will **NOT** work in any of those iterations, including the first two.

Comment: Yeah, i tried the above block of code, and for the first two conditions , it will work.
Can you explain what you find wrong here.

Comment: `destroy_all` will work for all three iterations, not only the last one. However, I cannot advise whether or not this is the "right" solution without knowing more context -- e.g. Are there any callbacks such as `dependant: destroy`? Are any of the `id` arrays extremely long?

Comment: `Model.where` will *always* return an instance of `Model::ActiveRecord_Relation`. Regardless of whether this collection is empty, or contains one record, or two records, or a million records. You can call `destory_all` on a collection, but you cannot call `destroy`. You can only call `destroy` on an individual record, not on a collection of records.

Comment: No callbacks are present. destroy_all is still failing for the first two iterations

Comment: In addition, your code is doubly wrong: `record.destroy if record` will always call `destroy` since your "record" is actually a **collection** of records, and even an empty collection is "truthy". So even if no record is found, your code will effectively be executing: `Model.none.destroy #=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)`

Comment: "destroy_all is still failing for the first two iterations" - I don't think so. We need a [mcve] to see the problem, because your words contradict what we know about rails/activerecord. And we trust us and rails more :)

Comment: Please give a [mcve] of the problem. Please include all necessary code. I can clearly see that the code you've posted will not behave in the way you've described, so can you please double check that you've explained the situation accurately.

Comment: @TomLord Thanks, it was my mistake, destroy_all is working fine now, and thanks for finding that `Wrong Argument` error. :)

Comment: OK, so to summarise: The only code you need in that loop is `Model.where(type: i, id: k).destory_all`. But, as I said above, there *may* be a better solution (speed/performance-wise) depending on the context of your application: Namely, you may be able to use `delete_all`, and you may greatly benefit from performing large-scale deletion in batches. I'd need to know more context to advise.

Comment: yeah, as `delete_all` skip all callbacks( I don't have any dependent destroy), i'm gonna go with that. Thanks

Comment: and to solve the `record.destroy if record` issue. I added `.present?`
so, now its `record.destroy_all if record.present?`, Now if it's empty, then destroy will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

In such a case you can use each

```
Model.where(type: i, id: k).each{|record| record.destroy}
```

It will work if none found so no need to check if it is there, on one occurance and on multiple.

You could also try `delete_all`

Comment: I think OP is confused about what worked and what didn't. Simply using `destroy_all`/`delete_all` should have worked in all 3 cases.

Comment: even shorter: `Model.where(type: i, id: k).each(&:destroy)`